# Combinatorics deck of card question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a deck of cards there are $4$ sets, each set has $13$ cards. 
you choose a series of n cards like this : you choose a card, you write it as the next 
 
in the series, you put it back in and you shuffle, you repeat it $n$ times. In how many ways 
each "ace" card will be chosen at least once ?

This is the exact way the question appears and i find the way that it is written really confusing. I'm thinking about subtracting options from all the options to get the answer but don't really know how to start. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your suggested approach is a good one. When you draw one card from the deck, in how many ways can it be something other than an ace?

Comment: Inclusion/Exclusion will do it.

Comment: like you take in first chance 3$\heartsuit$ then in second 4$\spadesuit$ and so on and this series of n cards must include ace? do 4 sets refer to $\spadesuit,\heartsuit,\diamondsuit,\clubsuit$

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion/Exclusion:
$$\small\binom41(52^n.n!-51^n.n!)-\binom42(52^n.n-50^n.n!)+\binom43(52^n.n!-49.n!)+\binom44(52^n.n!-48^n.n!)\\=\left[\left(2^4-1\right)52^n-4.51^n+6.50^n-4.49^n+48^n\right].n!$$